# Two-way data binding in Android or MonoDroid?

Tags: android, monodevelop

Does Android support XAML-like two-way data binding using Java or C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not natively. Take a look at [android-binding](http://code.google.com/p/android-binding/) though.

Comment: This should not longer be the accepted answer, because with the new Data Binding support library Android supports data binding natively.

Answer (score 1):

Android has an official data binding library. It takes care of two-way data binding. You can check the [official page](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html).

Comment: Actually with respect to user input it is not two-way data binding, only one way. To react to user input changes you still have to register a listenener and set the properties in your model yourself. Yet it is a vast improvement compared to findViewById() and the like.